Excluding pages from layout.tsx in NextJS 14.2.11
found.tsx file and I'm trying to remove my Header and Footer that are inside the Layout.tsx file. Now I know that the not found page needs to be in the app root folder but I wasn't able to find anything helpful.
If there is a way to bypass this or an alternative let me know.
I tried asking chatGPT, claude and I created multiple Layout.tsx files to bypass this which actually worked but I hope there is another way.
